# Existence of Limit of $x[1/x]$ as $x$ goes to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Find $\lim_{x \to 0} x[\frac 1 x].$
I want a formal $\epsilon\text{-}\delta$ proof.
I got the inequality for $x>0$, $1-x\leq x [\frac 1 x]\leq1$ by using definition of box function. How can I use this to find $\delta$ for any chosen $\epsilon.$

Comment: What is $[\frac 1 x]$?

Answer (score 2):

Using $\dfrac{1}{x}\geq \left\lfloor{\dfrac 1x}\right\rfloor>\dfrac 1x-1$, we have
$$0\geq x\left\lfloor{\dfrac 1x}\right\rfloor-1>-x\;\;\text{for }x>0\\
0\leq x\left\lfloor{\dfrac 1x}\right\rfloor-1<-x\;\;\text{for }x<0$$
Combining the two inequalities gives
$$\left|x\left\lfloor{\dfrac 1x}\right\rfloor-1\right|<|x| $$
so $\delta=\varepsilon$ will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Consider

$$x\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor=1-x\left\{\frac1x\right\}$$ where the fractional part remains in $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $1-x \le x\left\lfloor \frac 1 x \right\rfloor\le 1,$ then any value of $\delta$ small enough to make the distance between $1-x$ and $1$ less than $\varepsilon$ will also make the distance between $x\left\lfloor \frac 1 x \right\rfloor$ and $1$ less than $\varepsilon.$